# When I check tensorflow-gpu, I got an error: ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90:

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I tried check tf and I got an error. I tried install CUDA, cudnn and tensorflow. But I got an error. My code:

```
# check GPU?
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], 
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

Keras version:      2.2.4
Keras GPUs:         []
Tensorflow version: 1.13.1

What is wrong? I have no idea.
Output:

```
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.384.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: You have to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with cuda and nvidia driver, like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`. You can check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19362#issuecomment-390785762) as well.

Comment: @kruxx assuming he is on Linux!